# Java Audio DataLine.getLevel always returns 0

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to get the volume of an audio data line, and the method getLevel() returns 0.0

The API documentation is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#getLevel()

If anybody could shed any light, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while back and looking around found no good solution - it seemed to work on some platforms but not reliably.

I never figured out exactly why, but my workaround was reading the bytes off of the data line, and then at calculating the level via RMS (root mean square) of all the bytes in the last, say, 100ms (depending on what you want the update interval to be.) It's a simple bit of code but does the job nicely.

Comment: Ok thanks, I shall have a go at this when I am less tired. Strange how it does not work though.